# Three.js: How do I get cssRenderer layer element to be transparent showing webglRenderer layer through it?

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, three.js

This is a test of a cssRenderer running a scene directly in front of a webglRender, basically both running together, to fake the inclusion of html dom elements (div and text) in webgl.

I'm trying to make the textbox background (rendered inthe cssScene) transparent so you can see the floor (rendered in the glscene) behind.

The `cssObject` is mapped to `planeMesh` and the `planeMesh` has a zero opacity and `material.blending = THREE.NoBlending;`  on it. Here's the thing, blending seems to be having no effect, when I change the blending modes (with full opacity) nothing happens. And when I try some of the blending modes on `cssObject` also nothing happens.

The interesting thing is that if I spin the scene around and look through the back of the text box, even though the text is backwards the textbox is see through. Hmmmm... What's going on there and how do I make the text box see through with the text the right way around? :D

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rj2RM2KkCrrbLHLa4Goj?p=preview)

Here's the relevant js:

```
function drawMesh(){
// create the plane mesh
//var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ wireframe: false, color: 0xFF00FF });

var material   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
material.color.set('black');
material.opacity   = 0;
// material = THREE.DoubleSide;
material.blending = THREE.NoBlending;

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1.70,0.49);
  planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  planeMesh.position.x = 2.5;
  planeMesh.position.y = 1.8;
  planeMesh.position.z = -2;
  planeMesh.rotation.y = Math.PI / 1;


// add it to the WebGL scene
glscene.add(planeMesh);

var number = document.createElement( 'div' );
number.className = 'number';
number.textContent = "This is an html textbox and that is a cube. blah blah blah";
// create the object3d for this element
cssObject = new THREE.CSS3DObject( number );
// we reference the same position and rotation 
cssObject.position = planeMesh.position;
cssObject.rotation = planeMesh.rotation;


cssObject.scale.set(0.0075,0.0075,0.0075);
cssObject.rotation.y = Math.PI / 1;
cssObject.position.x = 2.5;
cssObject.position.y = 1.8;
cssObject.position.z = -2;

cssObject.blending = THREE.AdditiveBlending;
console.log(cssObject.position.x);
// add it to the css scene
cssScene.add(cssObject);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you remove this planeMesh from the scene and just give your cssObject a background-color ? http://plnkr.co/edit/bsUVriQjbl3TWHtogyb7?p=preview

Comment: That's a good idea to try, but it's movement is linked to the `planeMesh', that's how it's plugged into the webGL scene.

Comment: Ah I just saw your plunker, that's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish :D Why don't you make that up as an answer and I can check mark it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MeshBasicMaterial`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshBasicMaterial) has no `opacity` parameter.

You have to either set the `material = new THREE.Material();`
or, you can  remove this `planeMesh` from the scene and just give your `cssObject` a background-color in the css file.

[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bsUVriQjbl3TWHtogyb7?p=preview)